# Positioning an UILabel with a custom font in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uilabel

**EDIT: Just to avoid confusion - this question is about POSITIONING
with custom fonts! It is not about how to use custom fonts programatically!**

I am trying to get something like this in the interface builder:

[image]

As you see I am using custom fonts. Problem is that custom fonts
are not visibe in the interface builder so it is extremely hard
to position them there.

How do you manage situations like that. I am quite new to custom
designs in iOS apps and I have no idea how to start with this.

I think that maybe UICollectionView would be an answer here but
then still - custom fonts and positioning is anyway very hard.

Any ideas on how can I get positioning (not reflection) like
on the image above?

Comment: You can save your custom font in plist & from there you can easily fetch them where you want...

Comment: well, I know how to use custom fonts programatically - thing is that if I don't see them, how can I position them properly?

Comment: If you're really visual-spacial, then `CGRectDivide()` is perfect for this kind of stuff.

Comment: It looks like you could use three UILabels of equal size (if that works for you) and center the groups within each label.

Comment: I am using FontReplacer to set the custom fonts in interface builder. Have a look, might be helpful to you. https://github.com/0xced/FontReplacer

Comment: @Sohaib - as I said, I know how to use custom fonts.. I am asking rather about the fact that custom fonts are not rendered as such in the interface builder (you cannot just choose a custom font there in the font menu). What I am asking is about the idea on how to accomplish/position text (like on the screenshot) with custom fonts, as I tried many techniques in IB and nothing worked properly. It is hard to estimate sizes when you don't see the actual font on the screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see it's really complicated to do this in IB so `Do` it in your code. Set text and font to your label, and then retrieve it's size by following code:

```
+ (CGSize) heightOfString:(NSString*)string forFont:(UIFont *)font width:(CGFloat)width{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    size = [string sizeWithFont:font
          constrainedToSize:size
              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return size;
}
```

Now adjust the `labels` accordingly. If these are 3 you  can do it easily by seting `origin` of first `center` of second and origin from end of screen for last.